# phonegap - zooming in swiper.js slideshow

Tags: zooming, iscroll, swiper.js

i am working on an ios webapp which is going to be wrapped with phonegap, so that zooming in general is disabled and the viewport is not scalable.

I have got a slideshow for which i use swiper.js - and i use iscroll.js for the zooming function.

when i have zoomed into the picture and now swipe to look around on the zoomed frame, the swipe is interpreted in order to go to the next slideshow-image.

so my idea is it to add the class "swiper-no-swipe" to the slideshow when i am in zoom-mode and remove it when i have zoomed back to the original size.

i guess iscroll.js is using css-transform for the zooming function, so you have to request if the transform-value is more than 0 and then add the no-swipe class.

does anyone know how to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
    //NO SWIPE//
$('.swiper-slide').on('vmousedown', function(e) {

var matrix = $('.photo-aktiv').css('-webkit-transform');
var values = matrix.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
var n = values.toString(); 
var first = n.split(',', 1);
var länge = parseFloat(first);
if(länge>1){
     $(".swiper-slide").addClass('swiper-no-swiping');

}else{
    $(".swiper-slide").removeClass('swiper-no-swiping');
}

});
```